# How can I find all the files that a Windows executable has opened or access when it is running?

Tags: windows, file

I want to understand and track what an executable program/application/process is doing my computer. How can I find all the files (like ouput files, log files, etc.) that it has opened or is accessing when it is running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has a second pane, showing all open handles:

[image]

Also [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can monitor and log all registry and file access from a process.

Answer (score 3):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) sounds exactly what you are looking for.

Just find your process and it tells you in detail what the process is doing, more so than Process Explorer.